# SQL query to get all the data from different tables with same id

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, join

Sorry if this is too elemental but I cannot work it out. Don’t know how to search information on it either:

I have three tables:

Provider

```
id_provider  name   
---------- ----------- 
100         John 
101         Sam 
102         Peter
```

Contact

```
id_contact  RowNo   Email   
---------- ----------- ---------------- 
100          1      john@work.com
100          2      john@gmail.com
101          1      sam@work.com
101          2      sam@yahoo.com
```

Product

```
Id_product  RowNo   Product 
---------- ----------- ------------------------ 
100          1      John’s 1st product
100          2      John’s 2nd product
101          1      Sam’s 1st product
101          2      Sam’s 2nd product
101          3      Sam’s 3rd product
```

I need a query to show all the data from the three tables like this:

```
Id  name    id_contact  RowNo  Email     Id_Product  RowNo  Product

100  John    100         1  john@work.com    100       1   John’s 1st product
100  John    100         2  john@gmail.com   100       2   John’s 2st product
101  Sam     101         1  sam@work.com     101       1   Sam's 1st product 
101  Sam     101         2  sam@yahoo.com    101       2   Sam's 2nd product
101  Sam     null       null   null          101       3   Sam's 3rd product
102  Peter   null       null   null          null    null  null
```

I am trying all the joins I know but I cannot make it work.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT t1.id_provider AS Id, t1.name, 
       t2.id_contact, t2.cRowNo, t2.Email,
       t2.Id_product, t2.Product
FROM Provider AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT COALESCE(id_contact, id_product) AS id,
          c.id_contact, c.RowNo AS cRowNo, c.Email,
          p.Id_product, p.Product, p.RowNo AS pRowNo
   FROM Contact AS c 
   FULL JOIN Product AS p ON p.id_product = c.id_contact AND p.RowNo = c.RowNo
) AS t2 ON t1.id_provider = t2.id
```

The query does a `FULL JOIN` between `Contact` and `Product` tables and joins the table derived from the `FULL JOIN` to `Provider` table.

A `FULL JOIN` is required because we cannot know beforehand which of the two tables, `Contact` or `Product`, contains the most rows for each `id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from Provider P1
left join Contact C2
on C2.id_contact = P1.id_provider
left join Product P2
on P2.id_product = P1.id_provider
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  prov.*,
        c.*,
        prod.*
FROM    PROVIDER prov
        LEFT JOIN Product prod ON prod.id_product = prov.id_provider
        LEFT JOIN Contact c ON prov.id_provider = c.id_contact
                               AND prod.RowNo = c.RowNo
```

use left joins but join provider to product first then to contact

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/472b9/1)